# Multiple subdirectories for controllers in annotations.yaml

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-routing

I'm am trying to organize my controllers a bit more in a **Symfony 5.3** application. They are in a couple of subdirectories and use annotations for their routing. Here are some samples:

- ../src/StuffA/Controller/ControllerA.php
- ../src/StuffB/Controller/ControllerB.php

I now want to specify both inside my `annotations.yaml`. I tried several approaches, but could not find anything that works:

**Wildcards - Does not work**

```
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/*/Controller'
    type: annotation
```

**Multiple Paths - Does not work**

```
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/{StuffA,StuffB}/Controller'
    type: annotation
```

**Single Paths - Works but only for one Controller**

```
controllers:
    resource: '../../src/StuffA/Controller'
    type: annotation
```

Any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create multiple resource keys.

E.g.:

```yaml
# annotations.yaml
controllersFoo:
    resource: ../../src/Foo/Controller/
    type: annotation

controllersBar:
    resource: ../../src/Bar/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

I don't think you can use wildcards or glob patterns with the annotation loader.

Comment: I will probably end up having up to 10 such folders. Any other ideas on how to make it work without specifying each folder individually?

Comment: Having 10 keys does not seem to be a big issue, IMO. I don’t use annotations/attributes, so my configuration for everything is organized the way I want, separated from the code.

Comment: Just to sort of butt in here, I second the notion of using a routing file instead of annotations when you decide to move controllers elsewhere.  I use single action controllers and place those files wherever it makes most sense to me. No controller directories.  I once pitched the idea of using autoconfigure to load routes from controller files but it went nowhere.

Comment: Ok, I'll use multiple paths in annotations for now. Might switch over to routing.yml. I just likes to specify routing inside the controllers to have everything at the same place. I'll keep a look out for nice solutions inside routing.yml however.